# Why is a voigt model have a more physical meaning than a gaussian when looking at lineshape in spectrscopy?

Tags: spectroscopy

I was discussing this with my professor, he was saying that the Voigt model has a physical meaning in terms of actually being reproducible in physical terms when curve fitting to spectral lines. Lorentzian is the function normally associated with single atoms, not in a solid state matrix, but then he said Gaussian is just an easy way to explain line shapes but is more used in mathematics.

Any explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spontaneous emission results in a Lorenztian spectrum for an atom in vacuum with no external fields.

Atomic motion, inhomogeneous fields etc. lead to inhomogeneous broadening which typically has a Gaussian line shape.

If the line shape is dominated by spontaneous emission it’s basically Lorentzian. If it’s dominated by inhomogeneous broadening it’s basically Gaussian. If it’s in between then it has features of both. Specifically it’s a convolution of a Lorentzian and Gaussian which is a Voigt profile.

Comment: does this broadening from "Lorentz" to "Gauss" have anything to with the central limit theorem applied to the sum of the individual spontaneous emissions with random phases combined with the random Doppler shifts?

Comment: @hyportnex due to inhomogeneous fields or motions, different atoms have different transition frequencies. The distribution of frequencies is typically Gaussian (this is because the thermal velocity/position distribution is Gaussian). So you have an ensemble of Lorentzian with a Gaussian distribution of center frequencies. Mathematically this looks like a convolution of Lorentzian and Gaussian shapes.

Comment: What matters is that the underlying distribution of center frequencies is Gaussian. This may or may not be due to the central limit theorem.

Comment: @fermionicplants Does my answer address your question? If not, why? If you need to add additional information you can edit your question.

"... gaussian have nothing to do with real spectroscopy..." this is incorrect. Gaussians show up in real spectroscopy.

Comment: Yes your answer addresses my questions, thank you for your help.

Comment: I *think* (but am not sure how strictly true) that under the reasonable assumption that the atoms emit independently and with identical and smooth pdf with finite spectral moments of order $\le 3$ the Berry-Esseen theorem is applicable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem for cumulative distribution but with smoothness also for pdf, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series.

Comment: @hyportnex I think you're missing the physics here and getting mixed up in statistics. We can have a discussion in chat if you like. The central limit theorem is a thing, but it really isn't important here. The physical fact is that if you have an ensemble of atoms whose Gaussian distribution of center frequencies is (much narrower, much broader, about equal to) than the spont. emiss. line width then the measured spectrum will look like a (Lorentzian, Gaussian, Voigt).

Comment: @hyportnex the key is that in an inhomogeneously broadened sample the atoms do NOT have identical emission spectra. They each have a Lorentzian spectral profile, but the center frequencies varies from atom to atom because each atom has, e.g. a different Doppler shift (different relative velocity to the measurement device) or sits in a different B or E field resulting in a different Zeeman or Stark shift to the transition.

Comment: For identical atoms each atom has the same Lorentz pdf and has the same Doppler pdf, not the same Doppler shift but the same probability distribution of Doppler shifts, independently one from another. The combination of those two distributions is the effective emission from each atom, and then apply the CLT.

Comment: @hyportnex I don't know what you mean the Doppler pdf. At any moment in time all the atoms have different velocities, thus different center frequencies. We don't say that, at each moment in time, each atom has the same distribution of velocities.

Comment: I can see what you're trying to get at, but I think it's misguided. You're trying to say all atoms experience the same distribution of velocities, and the same Lorentzian distribution of emission about their distributed center frequencies. But I think, mathematically, the order of operations matters. And the time scales also matter. The emission is on much faster timescales than the atom samples different velocities. So the way to think about it is that, at each instant in time (where an instant is short compared to motional timescales, but long compared to emission timescales) the (1/2)

Comment: atoms have fixed but differing center frequencies (2/2).

Comment: Yes, now you see what I am getting at. Those differing center frequencies have an a priori distribution, too. Just as they have the *same* Doppler distribution, they also must have the *same* center frequency distribution tacitly assuming a quasi-equilibrium state for the ensemble.  By "tacitly" I mean that any external stimulus besides not complete spontaneity, if any, say, collisions or phonons, etc., that initiates emission is a small perturbation and leaves the atoms "intact". Perhaps the frequency distribution is quite different at and near the boundary compared to the inside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151112/discussion-between-jagerber48-and-hyportnex).